# ZfcUser - Check user login for every route

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

The question is :  How to check user login for every route in the application ?

I already think about the solution that create a base controller which has a checking function and then every other controller will extend from this one. And I will put the checking function on every action. It should work but is there any cleaner way for this using Zend Framework 2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the following zf2 module. It depends on ZfcUser and does exactly what you described https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize.

Basically it introduces a guard (there are several of them for your choice: controller guard, route guard) which listen on the MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE event and do the access check when the event is triggered